# How to adapt an unmanaged C++ DLL to be used by Ruby

Tags: c++, ruby-on-rails, iis, amazon-web-services, fastcgi

I need advice on converting a desktop C++ application to a web app.  (This is my first web app.)  The desktop app currently has a C# GUI, but the functionality I need to use all resides in an unmanaged, non-threadsafe C++ DLL.

The web-app uses Rails, and will run on a Linux server.  Mostly, it needs to pass a list of strings to the DLL and get a winnowed-down list in return.  The DLL will need to run on a Windows server.  It has a significant load time, so I want it to run persistently.  And I'll need multiple instances to handle simultaneous requests in a timely manner. I need it to scale reasonably well.  (In case it's relevant: The Windows server will be on Amazon Web Services.)

So I have to determine: (1) How to interact between Ruby and C++, and (2) how to manage concurrent requests.

**Ruby to C++**

I could use Ruby Extensions (perhaps with Swig or Rb++ to make it easier) to call the library from Ruby.  But is that an option when they're running on separate servers?

Regardless, with the relative simplicity of the interactions, I should probably just go with HTTP requests.  Right?

From what I've read, it sounds like FastCGI is the way to go.  I'll just have to wrap my DLL in a process with a FastCGI interface.  Is there any other option I should consider?

**Multiple Processes**

First I should clarify: The C++ DLL is not threadsafe.  So I need the server to spawn a configurable number of processes, and route requests to an idle process (or hold it in a queue till one becomes idle).

If I've understood correctly, [FastCGI in general supports this](http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/doc/www5-api-workshop.html), and [IIS in particular does too](http://phplens.com/phpeverywhere/fastcgi-php).  (Apparently IIS doesn't support multithreaded FastCGI applications, but that's fine for me.)

So will this just be a matter of configuring the FastCGI Process Manager?

Answer (score 0):

Look up ISAPI for IIS, then go Rails -> 'net -> Windows Server -> IIS -> ISAPI -> your ISAPI DLL plugin -> your HTTP webservice -> this DLL.

But that's a heck of a lot of hoops to jump through. Don't you have the source to the DLL?

If not, I would write a Windows test script which calls this DLL. Then I would writes tests that cover every single one of its behaviors. Then I would start a new project (maybe in Ruby, maybe in Gnu C++), and I would pass each one of those tests on the new project. I like to call this "extract algorithm refactor"; the result should be fresh code that does the same thing, more portably.

Comment: I just edited my question to be more clear: My DLL isn't threadsafe (making it threadsafe is non-trivial).  From what I'm reading, ISAPI requires thread safety--it doesn't have the "multiple single-thread processes" option that I talked about above. http://lyngtinh.blogspot.com/2011/07/difference-between-cgi-isapi-and.html

(Edit: Whoops, hit enter too soon.)

I do have the source.  What did you have in mind?

It's a large & complex library.  With my resource constraints, fresh code isn't really an option.

Comment: at the "your ISAPI DLL plugin" level, enforce thread safety by running the DLL in thread-specific memory. Or replace IIS with a C++ HTTP server that you can control, or ... patch.

Comment: Are you saying that IIS can spawn multiple copies of an ISAPI DLL, routing & queuing requests?  If so, I'll look into that.

Is it better than FastCGI in any way?

Comment: No, I'm saying if you have to write a ISAPI DLL, you can get inside that and invoke some kernel-level memory protection for each thread. But Apache works on Windows, so you could instead just use one of its mods...